# css global properties best practise?

Tags: css, inheritance

below these three code snippets which one would be the best one to implement in a style sheet ?

```
  *{
      box-sizing:border-box;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
    
    html,body
    {
    box-sizing:border-box;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
    
    html
    {
    box-sizing:border-box;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk selector `*` applies to *all* elements, not just the `html`/`body` element. You should avoid this, since you could be writing rules for a `div` later on and you wouldn't be able to give it any margin or padding (or change its `box-sizing`)! Use either the 2nd or 3rd snippet depending on whether you want to give the `body` any margin or padding.

Comment: ah, now i get it thanks alot :D